# react native webview event listener passes empty event object to callback

Tags: javascript, android, webview, react-native

building a html canvas page in react-native webview. everything seem fine except the `canvas.addEventListener` call the call back with empty event object

```
var moveEvents = ["mousemove", "touchmove"]
moveEvents.forEach(function (moveEvent) {
canvas.addEventListener(moveEvent, function(e) {
    console.log(e) // {} 
    mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
}, false);
```

don't know what could possible be wrong
this behavior is only noticed on react-native here is the code working as expected on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/freefony/wvy38fh6/4/)

Comment: Ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been struggling with the exact same thing. Regular events through DOM or jQuery didn't work for me, but the following did.

```
canvas.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    //e.pageX;
    //e.pageY;
};
```

Comment: Ah! weird. So it's our fault for treating this as DOM env when it's not. i read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804855/does-react-native-have-a-virtual-dom, and the articles sited. Thanks man for finding an answer to this.